# Scanner for 16.04

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm interested in a good scanner which should work good in Ubuntu 16.04 with a graphic program. Bestseller on amazon is canon lide 220, but there seems to be some problems with the driver. 
Can you suggest a good scanner?

Comment: we don't advice about hardware. for hardware there are websites you can use that focus on this. like http://sane-project.meier-geinitz.de/sane-supported-devices.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the version of SANE (acronym for Scanner Access Now Easy, the driver project for scanning on Linux) for Ubuntu 16.04, the default version is 1.0.14. Looking on the [SANE scanner model search tool](http://sane.alioth.debian.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=Canon&model=&bus=any&v=&p=) the support for that device is:

```
CanoScan LiDE 220   USB 0x04a9/0x190f   complete    GL124+ based, resolution from 75 to 4800 dpi
```

It looks like this particular model should work well on Linux. I do not have a device to confirm, however. If you are not specifically interested in that model, there are many others listed there on the site, which are older/newer/more featureful/etc.