# Is there a list of devices Ubuntu supports "out of the box"?

Tags: drivers, usb

I've been all over Canonical/Ubuntu's website and as far as I can tell there's no list of devices that are supported "out of the box," by which I mean "you can plug this in and it will work."   The closest I came was [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported), which unfortunately is sadly out of date and not nearly as helpful as it seems at first glance.

Ubuntu seems to be a fairly popular Linux distribution.   It installs cleanly, is stable, and seems to work fairly well.   I like it.   But I would think that there would be a list, somewhere on their site, that says "If you download this version, here are the devices it will support right out of the box, have a nice day."   But I can not find that page.

Does anyone know if Canonical maintains such a list, and if so, where is it?

[EDIT:  I should explain that I'm not an idiot, I've been a programmer/network administrator/system admin in the Windows world for 20+ years and I'm used to fiddling with stuff and tweaking it to get it to work.   But this experience was a level beyond what I'm used to in terms of difficulty.]

Comment: The best way to find out is by Googling "<Product Name> Linux" before buying it. I'm not aware of any compatibility list maintained by Canonical though.

Comment: Hardware certification: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/ and have a look here: https://www.linux.com/news/my-hardware-linux-compatible-find-out-here

Comment: RTL8192 drivers do come with Linux kernel, so you really did not have to run any makefile or installation.  Perhaps the dongle itself is malfunctioning. I've used 8192 dongles many times - have them installed on serveral computers in fact - and no issue whatsoever

Comment: 'Linux drivers' = 'Windows drivers' ! It means exactly zero. What distro, what version, which platform (x86, x64, arm, etc) ? Only preinstalled systems are fully compatible. A Windows guru should now that much.

Comment: RTL8192 work very badly. There is a DKMS package with good drivers in official repos now.

Comment: When I buy some hardware on amazon, I search there in comments for "Ubuntu" and "Linux". If I cannot find any information, I use the ask function there. Hardware recommends is offtopic here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/774389/scanner-for-16-04)

Comment: @nisargshah95 - thank you for that link!   I learned everything I needed from that link.  If you would like to make your comment an "answer" I will be happy to mark it Correct.

Comment: @user1071914 Posted it as an answer. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian has a similar page (don't know how frequently it is maintained). Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, it should help - wiki.debian.org/WiFi